Quad Topology for Ribbed Sphere
How I can fix the topology of the ends of the ridges over the surface of the sphere so that no creases form when using Subdivision modifier?

Without subdivision

With subdivision



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

First thing bevel your edge:

Then add the edges with the Knife tool, extrude and so on:

